# Trying to sort 2d array in python to output a list of highscores

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

So I am making a game server thing that lets users login and choose a game to play and then adds whatever score they got to a notepad file in the format: (ie blackjack) username, #chips, "chips". Now i want to sort through all the scores in the file to show on my gui but I'm not allowed to use built in functions like sorted but rather have to come up with an algorithm. I've tried a bubble sort and insertion sort without any luck. Here's what I have so far:

```
blackjackList = [['harsh', '4', 'chips'], ['ahmed', '25', 'chips'], ['yousef', '1003', 'chips'], ['krushangi', '200', 'chips'], ['bombberman', '1202', 'chips']]
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i][1]>alist[i+1][1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp
        return alist
```

This currently outputs

```
[['ahmed', '25', 'chips'], ['yousef', '1003', 'chips'], ['krushangi', '200', 'chips'], ['bombberman', '1202', 'chips'], ['harsh', '4', 'chips']]
```

when I use it with blackjacklist but i want it to make blackjacklist go in order from ascending to descending scores.

Comment: so change `>` to `<` to reverse the order it sorts?  What is the desired output?

Comment: I want it to order the list so the person with the highest score is first and lowest score is last

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the return statement is indented too much and sits inside the for loop therefore it only does one pass through before returning.

Also, you are comparing the numbers as strings. This will not give the expected order (e.g. "10" is less than "2"). You should use int() to convert them to integers which will then sort correctly.

Comment: ok so i changed that and it works fine for my blackjacklist highscores but now when i try to do it with my other list it doesn't work

Comment: What is your other list like?  I have expanded the answer to cover another issue which may be where your problem is.

Comment: wait i just checked again and it didn't work for blackjacklist here's what it outputted now:[['yousef', '1003', 'chips'], ['bombberman', '1202', 'chips'], ['krushangi', '200', 'chips'], ['ahmed', '25', 'chips'], ['harsh', '4', 'chips']]

Comment: yep so turns out i was comparing strings not ints and now it works fine thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use quicksort to sort the arrays.

```
>>> blackjackList = [['harsh', '4', 'chips'], ['ahmed', '25', 'chips'], ['yousef', '1003', 'chips'], ['krushangi', '200', 'chips'], ['bombberman', '1202', 'chips']]
>>> def quicksort(arr):
...     if len(arr)==0: return []
...     if len(arr)==1: return arr
...     left = [i for i in arr[1:] if int(i[1])<int(arr[0][1])]    # for descending, exchange
...     right = [i for i in arr[1:] if int(i[1])>=int(arr[0][1])]  # these two values
...     return quicksort(left)+[arr[0]]+quicksort(right)
...
>>> quicksort(blackjackList)
[['harsh', '4', 'chips'], ['ahmed', '25', 'chips'], ['krushangi', '200', 'chips'], ['yousef', '1003', 'chips'], ['bombberman', '1202', 'chips']]
```

The above code gives the ascending sorted list. To get descending sorted list, just exchange the values for `left` and `right` in the code.

Comment: Oh that's neat I haven't used that before. I'll give it a try, thanks!